# XCFramework with SPM dependencies does not expose them to project it's used in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have library that is a SPM package. It has one dependency.

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.9
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ExampleLibrary",
    platforms: [
            .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v13), .tvOS(.v13)
        ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "ExampleLibrary",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["ExampleLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.8.1")),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .target(
            name: "ExampleLibrary",
            dependencies: ["CryptoSwift"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ExampleLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["ExampleLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

This library is then build an exported to binary XCFramework and distributed as another SPM package

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.9

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ExampleSDK",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .macOS(.v10_15),
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "ExampleSDK",
            targets: ["ExampleLibraryFramework"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(name: "ExampleLibraryFramework", path: "ExampleLibrary.xcframework")
    ]
)
```

when I import this package to an app for usage and use

```swift
import ExampleLibrary
```

I have in this line error `Missing required module 'CryptoSwift'`

When I import `CryptoSwift` in the app as another package dependency I have an error:

`objc[5702]: Class _TtC11CryptoSwift15XChaCha20Worker is implemented in both [...]/ExampleLibrary (0x1016edcf0) and [...]/example.app/example (0x100611908). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

Also when I add to my XCFramework Package `CryptoSwift` dependency it also stops showing the error but the duplicate import is the same.

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.9

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ExampleSDK",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .macOS(.v10_15),
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "ExampleSDK",
            targets: ["ExampleLibraryFramework", "ExampleSDK"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.8.1")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "ExampleSDK", dependencies: ["CryptoSwift"]),
        .binaryTarget(name: "ExampleLibraryFramework", path: "ExampleLibrary.xcframework")
    ]
)
```

## Questions

1. How can I disable exposing `CryptoSwift` from my library so it can be imported in the app without duplicates? I've tried using `@_implementationOnly import CryptoSwift` inside my library but it did not stopped exposing it when I import another CryptoSwift in app.
2. How to make the app project see that this dependency is embedded inside the XCFramework. This is how XCFramework looks like inside:

[image: XCFramework folder structure]

Comment: You might look into this discussion on the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/issue-with-third-party-dependencies-inside-a-xcframework-through-swiftpm/41977/2   Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper unfortunatelly I tried this approach with `@_implementationOnly import ...` but this still produced issues as described ;/

Comment: Well, to cite Jordan Rose regarding the `@_implementationOnly` feature  on https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996  "if you want to play around with it, a reminder that this is unsupported, possibly buggy, and definitely not the final syntax.". When you use `@_implementationOnly`, you need to ensure that no symbol from CryptoSwift will be publicly exposed by your ExampleLibrary. Just to make that clear, but I believe you already did that.